# de4net and .net reactor v5 Deobfuscator

Tags: reflection, deobfuscation, .net-reflector

Best tools for Deobfuscator .net library is [`de4net`](https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) it's free and works good. in supported list i cant see .net reactor v5 . latest is 4.9 . is there any alternative way or modded version of `de4net` to Deobfuscate `.net reactor v5` obfuscated library ?

Comment: Your best bet is just adding on to de4dot or using dnlib (the library behind de4dot's functions)

Comment: i can not found binary or dll file of `dlbin` if there is any it very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you update to .NET Reactor >= v6.0 de4dot isn't even able to recognize that the files are protected with .NET Reactor (except "Native EXE File" is enabled).